# jQuery Ignore Undefined variable

Tags: jquery, var

I'm making an advice tool that works on adding up variables in jQuery.

Some multiple choice answers have a specific data attribute, which needs to be saved to a specific variable. If the user clicks on the same data attribute later on, the value must be added up to the previous value (that's stored in a var).

The problem: not every answer has a data attribute. Every time a user clicks on an answer without a data attribute, the variable changes to "Undefined" and it becomes unusable.

I converted a short version of my code to a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem:

```js
// The default is 0
var count_health = 0;
var count_fat = 0;

$('.question div').click(function(){
  
  // I want to get the data from the answer
  var gather_health = $(this).attr("data-health");
  var gather_fat = $(this).attr("data-fat");
  
  // And add it up to the variable
  count_health = +count_health + +gather_health;
  count_fat = +count_fat + +gather_fat;
  
  // And show it
  $('.health').text('Your health is: ' + count_health);
  $('.fat').text('Your fat is: ' + count_fat);
});
```

```css
.question div {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.health {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Shows health -->
<span class="health"></span>
<span class="fat"></span>

<!-- Questions & Answers -->
<div class="question">
  <h2>Do you run?</h2>
  <div data-health="1">Yes</div>
  <div>No</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <h2>Do you eat fruit?</h2>
  <div data-health="1">Yes</div>
  <div>No</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <h2>Do you eat chips?</h2>
  <div data-fat="1">Yes</div>
  <div>No</div>
</div>
```

I don't know if there's a more efficient way to calculate the variables. If you know one, I'd be happy to see it! But please be gentle, I'm not a jQuery wizzard like you guys :-)

Comment: well, what do you want to do if it has no attribute?

Comment: @EvanMosseri Nothing.. or treat it as "0". It only needs to use the present data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OR `||` operator like this works:

`var gather_health = $(this).attr("data-health") || 0; // or "" or any default set`

```js
// The default is 0
var count_health = 0;
var count_fat = 0;

$('.question div').click(function(){
  
  // I want to get the data from the answer
  var gather_health = $(this).attr("data-health") || 0;//<=== if attribute value is NaN set value to be 0
  var gather_fat = $(this).attr("data-fat") || 0;//the same here
  
  // And add it up to the variable
  count_health = +count_health + +gather_health;
  count_fat = +count_fat + +gather_fat;
  
  // And show it
  $('.health').text('Your health is: ' + count_health);
  $('.fat').text('Your fat is: ' + count_fat);
});
```

```css
.question div {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.health {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Shows health -->
<span class="health"></span>
<span class="fat"></span>

<!-- Questions & Answers -->
<div class="question">
  <h2>Do you run?</h2>
  <div data-health="1">Yes</div>
  <div>No</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <h2>Do you eat fruit?</h2>
  <div data-health="1">Yes</div>
  <div>No</div>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <h2>Do you eat chips?</h2>
  <div data-fat="1">Yes</div>
  <div>No</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was painfully simple. Thanks for the quick solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

you can just count it as zero like this (I used a ternary operator but you could have just easily used an if/else statement):

```
// The default is 0
var count_health = 0;
var count_fat = 0;

$('.question div').click(function(){

  // I want to get the data from the answer
  var gather_health = (typeof $(this).attr("data-health") != "undefined") ? $(this).attr("data-health") : 0;
  var gather_fat = (typeof $(this).attr("data-fat") != "undefined") ? $(this).attr("data-fat") : 0;

  // And add it up to the variable
  count_health = +count_health + +gather_health;
  count_fat = +count_fat + +gather_fat;

  // And show it
  $('.health').text('Your health is: ' + count_health);
  $('.fat').text('Your fat is: ' + count_fat);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! The thing with if / else statements is that it's unpractical with many variables and answers. I think Mamdouh had a shorter version of your answer, am I correct?

Comment: I appreciate your ingenuity though! :-)